# I am trying to change my blogger template

Tags: html, templates, blogger

I am trying to change my blogger template ..but as a beginner , I am having few issues with the code ..
what I want is to remove this column or whatever this area in red is .. it was for " latest stories "
http://postimg.org/image/8ry1ya8cr/

I am using freshlife template

what do you guys think I should change or delete in HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

Freshlife theme is two column blogger theme. I think maybe you have changed the width of the left column or you are using an additional div. Make sure your overall width of div is according to CSS box model. Means you count the actual width , padding, border and margin of both sides. Maybe this post can help you http://www.inopinion.in/2014/11/creating-blogger-template-from-scratch-1.html